# How to make a specific cell bigger in pgfgantt

Tags: pgfgantt

I have this code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{25mm}{25mm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}

\ganttset{calendar week text= \small {\startday}}

\begin{ganttchart}[
        hgrid,x unit=0.2em,
        hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
        vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
        time slot format=little-endian
        ]
        {25-11-2016}{4-06-2017}
    \gantttitlecalendar{ month=shortname,week=7} \\
    \ganttbar{Task A}{25-11-16}{10-02-17}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Diagram]

How you can see Nov and Jun are out of his cell, there is any way to do this specific cells bigger?

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is possible. I suggest changing the time slot specifier (tss) from `{25-11-2016}{4-06-2017}` to `{21-11-2016}{11-06-2017}`. This will give you an extra week at each end of the tss and create enough room for the month labels.

Comment: @Ross I take it, it's a good solution :)

Comment: @ross I agree this is the only practical solution. You should post it as an answer so that Draggluon can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the slots for the week identifiers is being set by `xunit=0.2em`. But as a result, there isn't sufficient space for the first and last month to be written without overlapping their borders. Changing `xunit` isn't an option as this would increase all the slots that identify weekly intervals.

The solution here is to add an extra week to the start and end of the time slot specifier (tss). By changing `{25-11-2016}{4-06-2017}` to `{21-11-2016}{11-06-2017}` and extra 0.2em is added to each end of the tss and there is sufficient space from writing the month label.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%\usepackage{anysize}
%\marginsize{25mm}{25mm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}

\ganttset{calendar week text= \small {\startday}}

\begin{ganttchart}[
        y unit title=1cm,
        y unit chart=0.7cm,
        hgrid,x unit=0.2em,
        hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
        vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
        time slot format=little-endian
        ]
        {21-11-2016}{11-06-2017}
    \gantttitlecalendar{ month=shortname,week=7} \\
    \ganttbar{Task A}{25-11-16}{10-02-17}
\end{ganttchart}
```